# SQL multiple select from another select query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there any way to do selects from a single `Select` in Microsoft SQL Server?

Something like :

```
SELECT id, type, name, address  
FROM Persons AS Persons_DATA 
WHERE (name='...' OR name in ('...','...'))

SELECT TOP 1 'Best Vendor : '+name from Persons_DATA where type=1 order by ...
union SELECT TOP 1 'Best Customer : '+name from Persons_DATA where type=2 order by ...
union SELECT TOP 1 'Least Debt : '+name from Persons_DATA where ... order by ...
union SELECT TOP 1 'Most Debt : '+name from Persons_DATA where ... order by ...
...
```

I know I can do :

```
SELECT TOP 1 
    'Best Vendor : '+name 
FROM
    Persons 
WHERE
    type = 1 AND (name='...' OR name in ('...','...')) 
ORDER BY ...

UNION

SELECT TOP 1 
    'Best Customer : '+name 
FROM
    Persons 
WHERE
    type = 2 
    AND (name='...' OR name in ('...','...')) 
ORDER BY ...
```

But I think this will take more time because it will do many unnecessary searches in a big data base

but the first code will only do 1 search in the big database and X searches in a small database and it will take less time.... am I right?

Comment: `TOP` without an `ORDER BY`? I don't understand what are you trying to do there.

Comment: Actually its just some test code the actual question is I want to do some sub-selects from a select

Comment: anyway , I added a ORDER BY to avoid misunderstanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CASE WHEN statement..

```
SELECT CASE WHEN type=1 THEN 'Best Vendor : '+name 
   WHEN type=2 THEN 'Best Customer: '+name 
    WHEN type=3 THEN 'Least Debt: '+name 
     WHEN type=4 THEN 'Most Debt: '+name ELSE '....'  END  
from Persons  A 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY type ORDER BY id DESC) Rk, name from Persons    
        WITH(NOLOCK) ) AS PS  ON PS.Id = A.id   and Rk=1
```

Comment: Oh thanks i think this will solve my problem but I guess you did a small mistake in CASE WHEN Syntax : https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp

Comment: Is there anyway to contain a count() or sum() in this querry? and I also dont understand this `LEFT JOIN (SELECT RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY type ORDER BY id DESC) Rk, name from Persons    
        WITH(NOLOCK) ) AS PS  ON PS.Id = A.id   and Rk=1  `

Comment: which count you want? type wise OR total sum?

Comment: select count of total rows with type 2 something like : Least debt : Customer , Total customers with debt : 100

Comment: Left join takes the latest record, instead of top 1 in each types

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194867/discussion-between-disco4uf-and-ponmani-chinnaswamy).